# Ultra Safe Nuclear Technologies (USNC-Tech) has delivered a design concept to NASA, but what does NASA consider a "design concept" to be?

Tags: nasa, engine-design, business, nuclear-propulsion, ultra-safe-nuclear-technologies

The 19-Oct-2020 Press Release [Ultra Safe Nuclear Technologies Delivers Advanced Nuclear Thermal Propulsion Design To NASA](https://www.prnewswire.com/news-releases/ultra-safe-nuclear-technologies-delivers-advanced-nuclear-thermal-propulsion-design-to-nasa-301154497.html) begins:

> SEATTLE, Oct. 19, 2020 /PRNewswire/ -- Ultra Safe Nuclear Technologies (USNC-Tech) **has delivered a design concept** to NASA as part of a study on nuclear thermal propulsion (NTP) flight demonstration. NTP technology provides unprecedented high-impulse thrust performance for deep space missions such as crewed missions to the moon and Mars. The NASA-sponsored study, managed by Analytical Mechanics Associates (AMA), explored NTP concepts and designs enabling deep space travel.

**Question:** In NASA-speak what exactly is considered to be proper, delivered "design concept"? Is it a design that could work, or more of an outline without the details? Is there anything like a prototype delivered for testing, or at least test results, or is it strictly a paper design?

The quoted paragraph includes "a study on... NTP flight demonstration" and when I hear "study" and "demonstration" I think of different things.

---

See also World Nuclear News' [USNC-Tech develops deep space propulsion system](https://www.world-nuclear-news.org/Articles/USNC-Tech-develops-deep-space-propulsion-system):

> Ultra Safe Nuclear Technologies (USNC-Tech) - a subsidiary of Ultra Safe Nuclear Corporation (USNC) - **has developed a design concept** as part of NASA-funded research into nuclear thermal propulsion (NTP) systems for potential use in deep space travel. The concept uses a specialised variation of USNC's proprietary fully ceramic microencapsulated, tristructural isotropic fuel, developed for use in power reactors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Design concept" sounds like it's [Technology Readiness Level 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technology_readiness_level#Current_NASA_usage): "technology concept and/or application formulated".  In short, what UNSC-Tech has delivered is a paper design for a rocket engine.  For comparison, [NERVA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NERVA) reached TRL 6, firing a prototype engine into a near-vacuum.