# How much power do radiation-based engines produce

Tags: artificial-satellite, propulsion, engines, fuel

I heard that the Voyager satellites used a radioactive source to power the computer and sensor systems. How much power can this technique produce nowadays?  Could it power, say, a fighting robot?  What materials could be used?  Is it legal for a civilian to get that much material?

Comment: different but related: [Most recent launch of a nuclear reactor, and current barriers to launching the next one?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/34139) and [What is the current status of Stirling engine-based radioisotope generator technology?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/36202) and [Ultra Safe Nuclear Technologies (USNC-Tech) has delivered a design concept to NASA, but what does NASA consider a “design concept” to be?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/49925)

Comment: Fighting people, or fighting ants?

Comment: @JonCuster, another fighting robot. They’re both the size of a large dog.

Comment: A 5.5 cm diameter ball of Pu-238 has a mass ~1.7 kg and puts out over 980 watts of heat. That's when it's fresh. After 87.7 years (it's half-life), you'll only have ~0.85 kg of Pu. It decays by alpha emission to U-234 (which has a half-life of 245,500 years). The alpha particles will neutralise to ~80 L of helium (at STP).

Answer (score 6):

The [Multi-Mission Radioisotope Thermoelectric Generators (MMRTG)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-mission_radioisotope_thermoelectric_generator) used by NASA are probably unfeasible for the purposes you are thinking of, although they are highly useful for space exploration. Multiple spacecraft have used these, including both *Voyager 1* and *Voyager 2*, *New Horizons*, *Curiosity*, and the new *Perseverance*. This is due to their ability to produce very stable amounts of energy for a long time. Unlike with solar panels, you also don't have to worry about how far from the sun you'll get.

According to [this NASA fact sheet](https://mars.nasa.gov/internal_resources/788/), the MMRTGs on *Curiosity* and *Perseverance* are able to supply 110 Watts of power. In comparison, [an average desktop computer](https://energyusecalculator.com/electricity_computer.htm) can use up to 300 Watts of power during peak operation. I highly doubt it could power a fighting robot. The reason these are used on space missions is because they provide very stable and constant power.

As for whether or not a civilian could get their hands on some, that would be a big no, for several reasons. While the [Plutonium-238](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plutonium-238#Use_in_radioisotope_thermoelectric_generators) used in them is not generally weapons-grade, it is still highly dangerous radioactive material.

It is also extremely hard to come by. It is difficult to produce, and the United States only produces a relatively small amount. The US recently restarted production of Pu-238 in 2013, but are only able to produce a [few hundred grams every year](https://www.forbes.com/sites/startswithabang/2018/12/13/nasa-doesnt-have-enough-nuclear-fuel-for-its-deep-space-missions/?sh=7fc696021c18). They hope to be producing at least a pound per year by 2023. However, each MMRTG requires 10.6 pounds of plutonium dioxide.

Use of plutonium is regulated by the [United States Nuclear Regulatory Commission](https://www.nrc.gov/materials/sp-nucmaterials.html), and I can't really see them giving 10 pounds of Pu-238 to a civilian when it's so hard to come by already.

Comment: RTGs are also used because they are very simple and very reliable. No moving parts, just a fancy [thermocouple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermocouple) to produce electricity from radioactive decay. You can use things other than Plutonium. [Polunium-210](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polonium-210), for example, provides 250x more power for the same mass and shielding, but it decays 250x faster. 25 MW for a few weeks might be enough to power a fighting robot, but it's *very* expensive and *very* toxic, so on second thought don't put it into your fighting robot.

Comment: I would say RTG-based "fighting robot" is technically possible but with one caveat - it can be active only for short period of time. :) Radoiactive RTG source can charge accumulatirs of the robot and then it can have period of "burst activity" with high power consumption - minutes, maybe couple of hours, until the accumulator is drained. But the recharge will be long (days?). It's exactly how Dragonfly copter is designed to operate on Titan, the Saturn's moon.